# nuxtjs2 - how to do disable for a single route or page in some case

Tags: nuxtjs2

##### nuxtjs2 - how to do disable for a single route or page in some case

I have just started nuxtjs framework. I want to disable some routes in one case. Is it possible to do or am I thinking the wrong way?